# Partial view renders as full view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, partial-views

MVC 3 , ajax, c#

My partial view is rendering as a new page instead of replacing the search results table.

Controller:

```
public class SearchController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Search/
    private myEntities db = new myEntities();
    private Repository repo = new Repository();

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new List<PersonViewModel>();

        model = repo.GetPeople();

        return View(model);
    }




    public PartialViewResult _SearchResult(string fname, string lname)
    {
        var personResult = repo.GetSearchResult(fname, lname);

        return PartialView("_SearchResult", personResult);
    }

}
```

The view:

```
<div class="page">

    <div class="middle-col-comment-mod">
                <h2>Search Existing Trespassers</h2>

        <div id="search">
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("_SearchResult", "Search", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", InsertionMode = System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "indexSearchResults" }))
            {
                <div class="editor-field">   
                    <label>First Name:</label>
                    @Html.TextBox("FirstName")

                    <label style = "margin-left: 15px;">Last Name:</label>
                    @Html.TextBox("LastName", "", new { style = "margin-right: 15px;" })

                    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="skbutton" value="Search" />

                </div>

            }

        </div>

                    <table id="indexSearchResults" class="data-table">
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                FirstName
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                LastName
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Gender
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                City
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                DOB
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                IsStudent
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Actions
                            </th>
                        </tr>

                    @if (Model.Count() == 0)
                    {
                          <tr>
                            <td colspan=7>
                                There are currently no trespassers in the trespass database.
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                                 <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Gender)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DOB)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.School)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsStudent)
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.PersonId }) |
                                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.PersonId }) |
                                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.PersonId })
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                    }
                    </table>

            </div>
    </div>
```

And the partial view:

```
@model IEnumerable<TrespassTracker.Models.PersonViewModel>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            First Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Last Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Gender
        </th>
        <th>
            Date of Birth
        </th>
        <th>
            Is a Student?
        </th>
        <th>
            Actions
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Gender)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DOB)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsStudent)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>

        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

From my research I found the usual suspect to be the missing link to the jquery script in the partial, but I had that.  I checked the network tab on my wed dev tools and found it is being called.  What else could the problem be?

Comment: I don't think you need the null before ajaxoptions. try removing it.

Answer (score 1):

the script won't cause any problem and the only thing I see wrong here is the table. you are trying yo fill the table with other table which returns a table, use a div instead to update the ajax form (search result):

```
<div id="indexSearchResults">
   <table>
     ..........
   </table>
</div>
```

Comment: how would this cause a full view problem?

Comment: actually, once it starts working, it is REPLACING the table with a table, not filling the existing table.  I tried your suggest anyway but it was no help.

Comment: @DaveA I was not sure, but mvc acts sometimes weird with not proper arranged tags, and I thought it could be one.

Comment: @teahou btw it could also happen if the unobtrusive ajax file is not loaded to page, check the page source to see it it's there correctly.

Comment: Yes the ajax script file is there, shows in view source, and I can see it being called in the network tab of web dev tools.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this 

    <div class="page">

        <div class="middle-col-comment-mod">
                    <h2>Search Existing Trespassers</h2>

            <div id="search">
                @using (Ajax.BeginForm("_SearchResult", "Search", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", InsertionMode = System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "indexSearchResults" }))
                {
                    <div class="editor-field">   
                        <label>First Name:</label>
                        @Html.TextBox("FirstName")

                        <label style = "margin-left: 15px;">Last Name:</label>
                        @Html.TextBox("LastName", "", new { style = "margin-right: 15px;" })

                        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="skbutton" value="Search" />

                    </div>

                }

            </div>


                        @if (Model.Count() == 0)
                        {

                            <label>There are currently no trespassers in the trespass database. </label>

                        }
                        else
                        {
                        foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
                           @Html.Partial("__SearchResult",item) 
                        }
                </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: No, still renders a new page.  It's like the ajax isn't working, but the script file is there.  Does anyone know if maybe ajax.beginform is not in the latest ajax jquery script?

Answer (score 1):

How 'bout to use jQuery do reload your result content, instead Post from your form? You can named some div with an ID and uses it as reference do **jQuery.load()** (considering you're using that ViewModel you passed into Index action):

1.View

```
 @model YourModel

 <!-- ... -->

 <div id="search">
     @using (Ajax.BeginForm("MainPostAction", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "yourFormID" })
     {
         <div class="editor-field">   
             <label>First Name:</label>
             @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName)

             <label style = "margin-left: 15px;">Last Name:</label>
             @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName, new { style = "margin-right: 15px;" })

             <input type="button" name="submit" id="searchButton" class="skbutton" value="Search" />

         </div>
         <div id="results"></div>
     }
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#searchButton').click(function(event) {
        $('#results').load('@Url.Action('_SearchResult', 'Search')', $('#yourFormID').serialize());            
    });
}
```

Your action remains the same.
How 'bout it?